# nginx not acknowledging passenger_root option

Tags: nginx, phusion-passenger

I'm running a sinatra app on passenger, and trying to hook it to nginx.
The relevant part of my config looks like:

```
http {
    passenger_root /path/to/gem; #this is a valid path
    passenger_ruby /path/to/ruby; #ditto

    #etc...

    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name hello.org;
        root /path/to/stuff/public;
        passenger_enabled on;
    }
}
```

Whenever I start nginx however, I get:

```
Starting nginx: [alert]: Phusion Passenger is disabled becasue the 'passenger_root' option is not set. Please set this option if you want to enable Phusion Passenger.
```

What am I missing here? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue as lowgain... using rvm + nginx, I installed passenger, which then recompiled nginx to include passenger stuff. Unfortunately, the old version was at /etc/nginx and the new version at /opt/nginx.

I had to remove nginx via apt:

sudo apt-get remove nginx

I also had to replace /etc/init.d/nginx with a new version. Once I was done with all that, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I had two installs of nginx after I rebuilt nginx with passenger support - the bash script was still reading from the old config!